# Iphone tableview time show in seconds

Tags: iphone

In iphone application
I have a table view having 5 rows. first row is for showing the decreasing digit like time in second. i.e 30,29,28.......0. this is for user to choose a action from table view within 30 seconds. how this will implement?

Thanks, Aaryan

Comment: Did you somehow sign out and forget you already asked this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279837/show-time-in-seconds-in-decrease-mode-in-table-view-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an NSTimer and update that row every second. 
Invalidate the NSTimer when it hits 0.